# How to find the intersection of 2 3d parametric equations

Tags: vectors, 3d, parametric

[Parametric Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KOXA.png)

I have 2 parametric equation, $$(100\sin(t),100\cos(t),2t^2+200)$$ 
and, $$(100\cos(s), 100\sin(s), 2s^2+160)$$ How do I find the interception of these two parametric equations. I have tried a lot using simultaneous equations but it is really hard and a nearly unsolvable algebra equation.
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I accidentally sent the question out incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint.* Set corresponding coordinates equal. The last one gives $t^2+100=s^2+80,$ or $$t^2+20=s^2.$$ This tells us that $s^2\ge 20,$ or in other words that $|s|\ge 2\sqrt 5.$ The others give $\sin t=\cos s$ and $\cos t=\sin s,$ or in other words $\cos s-\cos(π/2-t)=0$ and $\cos t-\cos(π/2-s)=0,$ or $$-2\sin(s-t+π/2)/2\sin(s+t-π/2)/2=0$$ and $$-2\sin(t-s+π/2)/2\sin(t+s-π/2)/2=0.$$ Can you now continue?

Comment: Ok so i get how you get everything up to $-2sin(s-t+\pi / 2) / 2sin(s+t- \pi / 2)/2 = 0 $ I don't understand how you got these equations.

Comment: @user234883 Use the trigonometric factor formula $$\cos x-\cos y=-2\sin\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{x-y}{2}\right).$$

Comment: Ok so setting them equal I can get $sin(s-t+\pi /2) = sin(t-s+\pi /2$ but I don't think is correct, as t = s, which does not make sense.

Comment: @user234883 No, you don't set them equal. Apply the fact that for real numbers if $AB=0,$ then $A=0$ or $B=0$ to the two equations of the form $-2\sin M\sin N=0$ in my answer.

Comment: There are too many solutions, I think I get that the property os $s^2>20$ but I don't know how to apply it. I have $$t+s - \pi /2 = arcsin(0)$$ , $$t-s + \pi /2 = arcsin(0)$$ , $$s-t + \pi /2 = arcsin(0)$$ , Im sorry to waste time its like 2 am, thanks

Comment: @user234883 Yes, the curves intersect in infinitely many points. What you have is that $s=πm,$ with $m$ being an arbitrary integer so that the condition on $|s|$ is satisfied, and $t=πm-π/2+2πk,$ with $k$ being an arbitrary integer.

Comment: But if my parametric equations had the restriction that $0\leq t\leq 10$ and $0\leq s \leq 10$ and I know there are two intercepts from solving graphically, what arbitrary integers for $m$ would I need to consider for restrictions.

Comment: @user234883 In that case you would have, for example that $0\le πm\le 10,$ or $0\le m\le 10/π,$ which says $m=0, 1, 2,$ or $3.$ You do something similar for the other parameter.

Comment: I may be wrong but from the graph, a point of intersection lies on $(47.95, -87.75, 213.95)$ or around that value. When inputting $s=\pi m , s=\pi , 2\pi ,3\pi$ and then inputting that into the parametric equation, $2s^2+160$ $$2*(\pi (1))^2+160 = 179.739 ...$$ or $$2*(\pi (0))^2+160 = 160$$, $$2*(\pi (2))^2+160 = 238.956...$$, $$2*(\pi (3))^2+160 = 337.6528...$$ These z components do not match the [graphical solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2KOXA.png) , $213.95$

Comment: @user234883 Are you sure your graph shows all intersections?